# Connecting to multiple Rails DBs, SQLite3 and SQLServer 2008

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2008, activerecord, sqlite

I’m trying to connect to a SQL server called Demand using this gem:
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/I'm

I'm following recipe #3 from the book 'Rails Recipes' http://pragprog.com/book/rr2/rails-recipes

Here’s my database.yml file:

```
demand:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: 172.21.148.01
  port: 1433
  database: Demand
  username: DEapp
  password: @pp1user
  timeout: 5000
```

From rails console, when I test the connection with `Demand.connection` i get the following:
(I know the addy and pw are good as i'm connected via toad currently, also created the model 'Demand' so rails would have an object)

```
> TinyTds::Error: Login failed for user ‘DEapp’. from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68:in
> `connect’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68:in
> `initialize’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:400:in
> `new’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:400:in
> `connect’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:198:in
> `initialize’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:35:in `new’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:35:in `sqlserver_connection’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:304:in
> `new_connection’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:323:in
> `checkout_new_connection’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in
> `block (2 levels) in checkout’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in
> `loop’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in
> `block in checkout’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in
> `mon_synchronize’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:260:in
> `checkout’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:162:in
> `connection’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:409:in
> `retrieve_connection’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in
> `retrieve_connection’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection’ from (irb):11 from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in
> `start’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in
> `start’ from
> /Users/drewgilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in
> `‘ from script/rails:6:in `require’
```

Any help? Here's the Pragmatic Programmer forum if you care to answer there as well: http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/189/topics/10476

Comment: do you have to use a mixed mode (using server ip address) authentication? or do you have an option of using windows authentication?

Comment: Can't use windows auth, it's a remote machine, actually I think it's a linux box, virtual windows. Do you think it's a problem with login?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that because the external DB user password started with the `@` symbol, rails wasn't happy about it because it thought it was and instance variable.

I changed the PW to something not starting wth `@` and it connected just fine.

```
    Drews-MacBook-Air:DE_App drewgilliam$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.3)
1.9.2p290 :001 > Externaldb.connection
  EXECUTE (36.7ms)  USE [DemandEstimator]
 => #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter version: 3.1.6, year: 2008, product_level: "SP1", product_version: "10.50.2500.0", edition: "Enterprise Edition (64-bit)", connection_options: {:adapter=>"sqlserver", :host=>"172.21.148.01", :port=>1433, :database=>"DemandEstimator", :username=>"DEapp", :password=>"demand_app_user", :timeout=>5000, :mode=>:dblib}> 
1.9.2p290 :002 >
```